# Transfer files from blob storage to vm

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, blob

I want to upload files from blob to virtual machine I created, how can I do it?
Also what is better - uploading from blob to vm or downloading to vm from blob?

Answer (score 0):

Downloading from VM to blob is probably easiest. You can do this in many ways including:

- [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy)
- [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell)
- [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet)

These can all be scheduled with the standard Windows task scheduler.

Comment: I would use this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell for PowerShell.